# How to compile C++ project of Visual Studio through command line on windows?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, cmake

Now I have a face detection task. Detecting faces and extract the face area to save them. The program accepts two parameters. One is the source directory C:\data\src, and another is the target directory C:data\des.

Basically, we can compile the program and run it by VS2013. But now I want to  compile and run the project by **Command Line** on another computer of windows that **hasn't Visual Studio**! How can I do it!

**In short, I need to write a interface to the program so that others can use it conveniently. Because others may have not VS Development Environment**

There are two kinds of environmental dependencies, and the VS configuration is as follows.

**One is opencv3.1:**

1. C ++ include directory

   - opencv \ build \ include
   - opencv \ build \ include \ opencv
   - opencv \ build \ include \ opencv2
2. Library directory

   - opencv \ build \ x64 \ vc12 \ lib

**Another is dlib 18.17:**

1. C ++ include directory

   - dlib-18.17 \ dlib \ all
   - dlib-18.17 \ dlib \ external \ libjpeg
   - dlib-18.17 \ dlib \ external \ libpng
   - dlib-18.17 \ dlib \ external \ zlib
2. Library directory

   - dlib-18.17 \ dlib
   - dlib-18.17 \ dlib \ external

Comment: Why do you need to compile it more than once? Just distribute the executable.

Comment: Thank you! Is a VS project can run without VS? How can I get a executable project?

Comment: Almost every windows program you currently have was done in a version of Visual Studio, it's purpose is to create standalone programs. Just copy the executable to target computer and see if any DLL is missing and include those as well. Just don't distribute the Debug version of your build. That one will not run unless you also have the same Visual Studio version installed in target PC.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I will try the Release version! But Actually, my project was divided into several functional model such as detect face, classification, each model should have a program entry(main function accepted parameters). I would like to call each file separately to complete different functions.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a compiler, and if you have the Visual Studio Compiler, you'll have the IDE, except in some corner cases, in which you'll still have `msbuild`, which is what you're after.

If you want to support other compilers (e.g. GCC from e.g. MinGW-w64), I strongly suggest a cross-platform build system such as CMake to generate your VS project files and e.g. Ninja files for other systems.

Comment: Thank you! I want to use the CMake tools to compile the source code! Is I need to write a CMakeList.txt? I don't know how to write it.